# How to print an Array on one line

Tags: php, html, arrays

I've searched for answers but none have related directly or i haven't been able to adapt it to fix my problem

How would I print the following in one line

```
<?php

$product_array = array("id"=>001, "description"=>"phones", "type"=>"iphone");


print "Print the product_array = ";
print_r($product_array);

?>
```

**Current result**

Print the product_array =Array

> (
>
> [id] => 001
>
> [description] => phones
>
> [type] => iphone
>
> )

**Wanted Result**

> Print the product_array =Array ( [id] => 001 [description] => phones
>   [type] => iphone )

Comment: By default, it should be rendered in one line at your browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$arrayString = print_r($array, true);
echo str_replace("\n", "", $arrayString);
```

The second value of print_r lets the function return the value instead of printing it out directly.

Answer (score 10):

If you're just looking to view the contents of the array for monitoring or debugging purposes, perhaps encoding the array as a JSON would be useful:

```
print "Print the product_array = " . json_encode($product_array);
```

Result:

> Print the product_array = {"id":1,"description":"phones","type":"iphone"}

---

Alternatively, you could use the [`var_export` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to get a parsable representation of the variable and then simply remove all the new line characters in the string.

> **`var_export`** — Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable

Here is a simple example:

```
$str = var_export($product_array, true);
print "Print the product_array = " .  str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $str);
```

This will give you exactly the result you specified:

> Print the product_array = array (  'id' => 1,  'description' => 'phones',  'type' => 'iphone',)

---

**I would recommend the first option since it requires less "manipulation" of the strings - the second option starts to perform replacements where as the first simply provides a readable output right away.**

Comment: Simple, and doesn't require multiple lines of source code, for the convenience of more concise output. Definitely better than the accepted answer, which seems to get hung up on having to use `print_r`.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo str_replace("\n", '', print_r($product_array, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is possible to replace several different chars (for example line break and null) at the same time, e.g.:

```
echo str_replace(array("\n", "\0"), "", print_r($product_array, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
$width = 150;
$height = 100;

print json_encode(compact('width')) . PHP_EOL;
print json_encode(compact('height')) . PHP_EOL;
```

The output is:

```
{"width":369}
{"height":245}
```

The added benefit is that you can do multiple variables into the compact function at once:

```
print json_encode(compact(['width', 'height'])) . PHP_EOL;
```

The output in this case is:

```
{"width":369,"height":245}
```